# Printing from a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am working with Python 3.2 and I have a list where the elements may vary in number depending on the original input. How can I print the elements from the list, but add 'and' before the last element when I  don't know the exact number of elements in the list?

Comment: So `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is `1, 2, 3, 4 and 5` ?

Answer (score 3):

For a list called `floep`

```
print('%s and %s' % (', '.join(floep[:-1]), floep[-1]))
```

As commented, a mapping might be needed for non-strings

```
print('%s and %s' % (', '.join(str(x) for x in floep[:-1]), floep[-1]))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with python 3.2 so I could be totally off base though but will ''.join work on a list of ints? I have to map(str,list) before I can join in python2.7

Comment: Saying `map(lambda x: str(x), ...` when you can say  `map(str, ...`  looks kind of silly.

Comment: Okay how's this? `[str(x) for x in floep[:-1]]` Prettier?

Comment: I would use a generator expression like this: `','.join(str(x) for x in floep[:-1])`.

Answer (score 2):

for a list, `a`

```
a = map(str, a)
print(', '.join(a[:-1]) + ', and ' + a[-1])
```

edit: I believe IamAlexAlright was right about needing a `map` first

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    if i=len(list)-2:
        print('and')
    print(len[i])
```